# How to run(sync) multiple .js files from a directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronization

I'm trying to run multiple .js files from a directory:

**exampleDir/test.js**

```
console.log('hi');
```

**run.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const {execFileSync} = require('child_process');

const testsFolder = './exampleDir/';

const files = fs.readdirSync(testsFolder);

const funcs = files.map(function(file) {
    const out = execFileSync(`node ${testsFolder}${file}`);
    console.log(out.toString());
});
```

however I get:

```
> example@1.0.0 test /home/perdugames/example
> node ./run.js

child_process.js:624
    throw err;
    ^

Error: spawnSync node ./exampleDir/test.js ENOENT
  ...
```

Comment: Try passing the full path to node, run `which node` on terminal if you dont know the full path

Answer (score 0):

File paths should be specified unambiguously, preferably independent of current working directory and relative to current module. To create a new Node process, there are `spawn` and `spawnSync` in `child_process`:

```
...
const path = require('path');
const testsFolder = path.join(__dirname, './exampleDir/');
const files = fs.readdirSync(testsFolder);

const funcs = files.map(function(file) {
    const filePath = path.join(testsFolder, file);
    const out = spawnSync(filePath);
    console.log(out.stdout.toString());
});
```